# Slideshow Extender not Working with ASP.Net Routing

Tags: asp.net, routes

I want to implement image slideshow using asp.net ajax slideshow extender in my web forms application page in which ASP.Net Routing is implemented. But unfortunately the Slideshow is not working. I tried to debug it, but It's not calling the method of the Web Service used to get the slides. I even tried to assign the source of web service file using ResolveClientURL, but still, it's not working.

Do let me know if anyone has a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. It is not an issue related to URL Routing. In fact, I was missing a namespace directive in my web service code, as a result it was not getting called. It works without using ResolveClientURL() function.